# How to concatenate two or more audio files as fast as voicememo app in ios?

Tags: concatenation

I already have tried to concatenate two audio files using AVAssetExportSession, but it was very slow when concatenating two large audio files.

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,

Comment: Hi, thanks for your concern